# How to make the content displayed depending on a particular user kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

There will be no code in this question. Imagine that I have an application in which there is a full user registration, after registration, an account is logged in. Let it be a sneaker store. So, here is a list of all products (RecyclerView), the user can add some product to his favorites. The question is how to make sure that each registered user has his OWN favorites list, so that he naturally does not see someone else's. I am interested in how this can be done via Firebase or ROOM Database.

If you shorten the question, it may sound like this: how to make the content displayed depending on a particular user

Comment: Does MikeT's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be a many-many relationship so in room you would have a table for the users, a table for the item that can be made a favourite and then a table that maps a user/favourite combination. This table would typically just store two references/relationships/maps/associations ... one to the user and the other to the favourite.

As such an item can be made a favourite by many users and a user can have any favourites. You would extract the list of a users favourites using a SELECT query that has a WHERE clause of the reference to the user.

As a working example using Room:-

The **User** table (Entity in Room) :-

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey
    val userId: Long? = null,
    val username: String,
    val userPassword: String
)
```

The **Item** table/entity :-

```
@Entity
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey
    val itemId: Long? = null,
    val itemName: String
)
```

The mapping/relationship/associative .... table **UserItemFavourite** :-

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["userIdMap","itemIdMap"],
    /* Foreign Keys enforce referential integrity */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = User::class, parentColumns = ["userId"],childColumns = ["userIdMap"], onDelete = CASCADE, onUpdate = CASCADE),
        ForeignKey(entity = Item::class, parentColumns = ["itemId"],childColumns = ["itemIdMap"], onDelete = CASCADE, onUpdate = CASCADE)
    ],
    indices = [Index("itemIdMap")]
)
data class UserItemFavourite(
    val userIdMap: Long,
    val itemIdMap: Long
)
```

A POJO (not an entity) for getting the User with the list of Favourite Items **UserWithFavouriteItems** :-

```
data class UserWithFavouriteItems (

    @Embedded
    val user: User,
    @Relation(
        entity = Item::class,
        parentColumn = "userId",
        entityColumn = "itemId" ,
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = UserItemFavourite::class,
            parentColumn = "userIdMap",
            entityColumn = "itemIdMap"
        )
    )
   val itemList: List<Item>
)
```

Another POJO (bonus) for getting the count an item is a favourite:-

```
data class FavouriteItems(
    @Embedded
    val item: Item,
    val favouredcount: Long
)
```

Some Dao's (database interaction functions) **AllDao** "-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(user: User): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(item: Item): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(userItemFavourite: UserItemFavourite): Long
    @Query("SELECT coalesce(userid,-1) FROM user WHERE username=:userName AND userPassword=:password")
    abstract fun login(userName: String, password: String): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    abstract fun getAllusers(): List<User>
    @Query("SELECT * from user WHERE userid=:userId")
    abstract fun getUserWithFavouriteItems(userId: Long): UserWithFavouriteItems
    @Query("SELECT item.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM useritemfavourite WHERE itemIdMap = itemid) AS favouredcount FROM item ORDER BY favouredcount DESC")
    abstract fun getFavouriteItemsList(): List<FavouriteItems>
    @Query("SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM user) + (SELECT count(*) FROM item) > 0")
    abstract fun isData(): Boolean

}
```

The Database (@Database) class (tells the database it's entities and allow instances of the dao(s) to be obtained via an instance of the database) this one also includes obtaining an instance of the Database :-

```
@Database(entities = [User::class,Item::class,UserItemFavourite::class],version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        var  instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    TheDatabase::class.java,
                    "thedb.db"
                )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- for convenience/brevity demo can be run on the main thread

Finally putting it all together in an Activity :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    val TAG = "USERINFO"
    var currentUserid: Long = -1L;
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        val passwordAttempts = listOf<String>("notpasswordsarah","passwordsrahnot","passwordsarah")

        addSomeData()
        for(s: String in passwordAttempts) {
            if (login("sarah",s)) break
        }
        val currentUserWithFavourites = dao.getUserWithFavouriteItems(currentUserid)
        Log.d(TAG,"User logged in is ${currentUserWithFavourites.user.username}. Favourites are :-")
        for (i: Item in currentUserWithFavourites.itemList) {
            Log.d(TAG,"\tFavourite Item is ${i.itemName}")
        }

        val favouriteItems = dao.getFavouriteItemsList()
        for (fi in favouriteItems) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Item is ${fi.item.itemName} favourite count is ${fi.favouredcount}")
        }

    }

    private fun addSomeData() {
        val test = dao.isData()
        if (!dao.isData()) {
            val u1 = dao.insert(User(username = "Fred",userPassword = "passwordfred"))
            val u2 = dao.insert(User(username = "mary",userPassword = "passwordmary"))
            val u3 = dao.insert(User(username = "sarah",userPassword = "passwordsarah"))
            val i1 = dao.insert(Item(itemName = "Book"))
            val i2 = dao.insert(Item(itemName = "Diary"))
            val i3 =dao.insert(Item(itemName = "Pad"))
            val i4 = dao.insert(Item(itemName = "Pencil"))
            val i5 = dao.insert(Item(itemName = "Pen"))
            val i6 = dao.insert(Item(itemName = "Highlighter"))
            val i7 = dao.insert(Item(itemName = "Ruler"))
            val i8 = dao.insert(Item(itemName = "Compass"))

            dao.insert(UserItemFavourite(userIdMap = u1, itemIdMap = i1)) /* Fred has Book */
            dao.insert(UserItemFavourite(userIdMap = u1, itemIdMap = i5)) /* Fred has Pen */
            dao.insert(UserItemFavourite(userIdMap = u1, itemIdMap = i7)) /* Fred has Ruler */
            dao.insert(UserItemFavourite(userIdMap = u3, itemIdMap = i2)) /* Sarah has Diary */
            dao.insert(UserItemFavourite(userIdMap = u3,i7)) /* Sarah has Ruler */
        }

    }

    private fun login(username: String, password: String): Boolean {
        currentUserid = dao.login(username,password)
        if (currentUserid > 0 ) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Successfully Logged In.")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Login unsuccessful.")
        }
        return currentUserid > 0
    }
}
```

The **Result** output to the log :-

```
2021-07-19 13:56:09.820 D/USERINFO: Login unsuccessful.
2021-07-19 13:56:09.821 D/USERINFO: Login unsuccessful.
2021-07-19 13:56:09.822 D/USERINFO: Successfully Logged In.
2021-07-19 13:56:09.828 D/USERINFO: User logged in is sarah. Favourites are :-
2021-07-19 13:56:09.828 D/USERINFO:     Favourite Item is Diary
2021-07-19 13:56:09.828 D/USERINFO:     Favourite Item is Ruler
2021-07-19 13:56:09.830 D/USERINFO: Item is Ruler favourite count is 2
2021-07-19 13:56:09.830 D/USERINFO: Item is Book favourite count is 1
2021-07-19 13:56:09.830 D/USERINFO: Item is Diary favourite count is 1
2021-07-19 13:56:09.830 D/USERINFO: Item is Pen favourite count is 1
2021-07-19 13:56:09.830 D/USERINFO: Item is Pad favourite count is 0
2021-07-19 13:56:09.830 D/USERINFO: Item is Pencil favourite count is 0
2021-07-19 13:56:09.830 D/USERINFO: Item is Highlighter favourite count is 0 
2021-07-19 13:56:09.831 D/USERINFO: Item is Compass favourite count is 0
```

***IMPORTANT** The above code is only meant to be a demonstration and is therefore concise and lacking in some aspects that would(should) not be acceptable for a published App.*